# Bootstrap img with color overlay not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have an img that is responsive with Bootstrap. I want to add an overlay color of this to the image.  `background-color:#110022;`

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/1h8Lk11j/5/

In the image, I want the darker portion of the image to be the same size of the image but I can't get it right.

The problem is that the image overlay does not scale with the screen size and I would like it to be the exact same size of the image. I tried a parent div with relative positioning and it didn't work for me.

I am currently using a div container to act as the overlay for the image but it doesn't seem to be a good solution to be responsive.

```
<div class="container-full">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center">
          <h1 class="calltoaction">Insert some Text here</h1>
          <br><br><br>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container full -->
```

CSS

```
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;

  width: 100%;
   min-height:100%;
   background-color:#110022;
  color:#eee;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.bgimage {
       position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

EDIT: I have already read the thread before I posted my questions. The solution did not work for me.

Comment: I worked on this solution https://jsfiddle.net/1h8Lk11j/6/, before it was closed. Maybe it will help you

Comment: I was working on the solution as well: https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1h8Lk11j/8/ and maybe this will help you too.

Comment: Seriously now, in which way don't the answers to the other question work?